# ruby on rails pass parameters from a form to a ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to execute a Ruby script that uses parameters passed to it from a Ruby on Rails form.

This is a snippet from my from:

```
<%= form_for(@test, :html => {:name => "test", :id => "test"}) do |f| %>
    <div class="field", id="configure_device">
        <%= f.label  "Label1" %>
        <%= f.text_field :Form_Param1 %>
        <%= f.label "Label2" %>
        <%= f.text_field :Form_Param2 %>
        <%= f.label "Label3" %>
        <%= f.text_field :Form_Param3 %>
```

<... more text_fields here ...>

```
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= button_to 'Apply Configs', :remote=>"true" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My Ruby script's structure is as follows:

```
def apply_configs (param1, param2, param3, ..., etc.)
    <... ruby code that executes based on the values passed in param1, param2, param3 ...>
end
```

I tested this Ruby script separately and it works just fine if it receives the right input parameters param1, param2, param3, ..,, etc.

Te question is how can I execute this Ruby script when the "Apply Configs" button is clicked and how can I pass to it parameters Form_Param1, Form_Param2, Form_Param3, ..., etc. to be mapped to param1, param2, param3, ..., etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to receive it from `params` , there are no need of `arguments`

```
def apply_configs
   form_param1 = params[:test][:Form_Param1]
   form_param2 = params[:test][:Form_Param2]

   // similarly

    <... ruby code that executes based on the values passed in param1, param2, param3 ...>
end
```

Comment: Thanks dku. I made those changes. I'm a beginner with RoR so my challenge now is how to trigger that script from the form? say "def apply_configs ..." is in file apply_configs.rb under app/views/test or anywhere else, then what do I configure in the button_to to get that Ruby script executed when the button is clicked?